# Change collation of AsyncMysqlClient

Tags: hacklang

How can I change the collation of `AsyncMysqlClient` (or `AsyncMysqlConnection`, I am not sure which one of them) to `utf8`?

I read the documentation, but I cannot find any method for changing the charset. I am probably missing it, if it's actually there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, we don't actually expose a way to set the encoding of an async connection in the [API](https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/reference/class/AsyncMysqlConnection/). It would technically be possible to use [AsyncMysqlClient::adoptConnection](https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/reference/class/AsyncMysqlClient/adoptConnection/) to create the connection via MySQLi and set the encoding before passing it to the async system, but I wouldn't recommend doing it that way.

Instead, as suggested [here](http://blog.oneiroi.co.uk/mysql/mysql-forcing-utf-8-compliance-for-all-connections/), you could set the encoding of the connection explicitly via SQL with:

```
SET collation_connection = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
SET NAMES utf8;
```

If you have access to the configuration of the MySQL server itself, you can use `init_connect` to have the statements run at the start of every, non-root, connection:

```
[mysqld]
init_connect='SET collation_connection = utf8mb4_unicode_ci; SET NAMES utf8;'
default-character-set=utf8
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Comment: For some reason, setting those commands in the server configuration does not bring success. However I managed to get this done by passing those statements as queries on each connection's open

Answer (score 1):

Think you have to try to change the charset on the connection you get via AsyncMysqlClient->connect?

Comment: How exactly? `connect` method doesn't have any `options`-like parameter

Comment: @Victor Not the connect method itself but the object you got from the connect method?